# Best way to verify that untrusted node code doesn't send information over the network

Tags: node.js

I am hoping to use two untrusted node files.  I want to be sure that they don't send any information over the network maliciously.  I have access to the source code and have read it some what carefully but it is quite lengthy and complex, and some of it is minified, and someone writing very sneaky code could potentially do something tricky that I might have missed.

Is there an easy way to be sure (ie if it doesn't use the request or socket modules) that it cannot possibly be sending any data out over the network.

The code only requires the sys, fs, and tail modules and I will be running it without the request or socket module installed.

I am very new to node, are the other easy precautions that I can take?

Comment: Run it in a LXC container which does not have network access.

Comment: socket and request are only wrappers for lower level node functionality, it may be possible for it to send data without requiring anything, also, you don't have to require things at the top of the file where they are easy to see, if you havn't, search for "require" to double check.

Comment: @alex can you point me in the direction of how to set up such an LXC container on windows, the code needs to hit the windows file system.

Comment: @asutherland, it's impossible. Virtual containers are a server-side task, and windows isn't great in those (to say the least). If you need to run it on desktop computers under windows, run it inside VirtualBox, but it might cause some performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

#### This process is good for anything suspect, not just node.js

General Precautions:

- run inside a virtual machine
- ensure the host is adequately firewalled
- run Wireshark locally to observe network traffic requests

Sometimes you need to go a step further. Some programs (on Windows in particular) can actually tell if you are attempting monitoring... (although I'd be a little surprised if a Javascript program could do that).  But doing this can be educational anyway.

- set up a second machine that acts as a gateway to the network
- ensure it is adequately firewalled
- connext the test machine physically only to the gateway
- run [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) on the gateway and observe traffic from the test machine

That wont catch everything, you should still monitor with wireshark what happens in a real situation in case any traffic is context dependent.